# How can permutation test be used for assessing the prediction capability of a model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, prediction, permutation-test

I have a set of real labels $(y_1, y_2, ...,y_n)$ and predictions $(\hat{y}_1, \hat{y}_2, ...,\hat{y}_n)$ produced by my model. My supervisor has told me to assess the significance of the predictions by using a permutation test.

I'm very new to permutation test and I tried using the code from this site: http://spark.rstudio.com/ahmed/permutation/

What I got was a very high P-value of more than 0.9. I started to wonder if I did something wrong.

How is permutation test used in testing if my prediction results are statistically significant or not?

Comment: A permutation is for testing some hypothesis. What's the null hypothesis? What's the test statistic?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, I wasn't given any test statistic and that's what I'm kinda also asking here. What would be a test statistic in this kind of a situation? What would you do if your're predicting e.g. temperature.

Comment: If you have no test statistic, how on earth did you get a p-value?

Comment: I used the difference of the means of labels and predictions as the test statistic as was used in the link I gave. I just tried it but I don't know what statistic I should use here.

Comment: @Glen_b my supervisor told me to do a permutation test, but I was not given any test statistic. That's why I asked my question here. What kind of test statistic is usually used in a situation like this to evaluate whether the prediction performance is significant or not?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b Thank you for your reply. Could you give an example as an answer? I can accept it. Maybe I'm crying for an example because I'm a first timer with permutation test x)

Comment: jjepsuomi -- I really don't understand enough about what you're doing here to give reasonable advice. I've never seen a permutation test used this way, and while I can conceive of ways to use one, I don't know how useful they are in a situation you've explained so little about. Is correlation different from 0 / MSE lower than a plain mean prediction useful?

Comment: @Glen_b I have my set of labels and predictions. I have calculated a performance measure called concordance index (C-index) for my predictions. Now what I think my supervisor told me was to do this: Use permutation test (by shuffling the predictions) to see how likely it is to get this C-index by a chance. Does that help?

Comment: Yes! That's an explicit null and an explicit test statistic, as well as explicit instructions on how to do it. To my eyes, you just answered your own question. What do you need help with there?

Comment: How big is $n$?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b thank you for that =) I think indeed I solved my own problem then :D thank you! I have 11795 data points, but you don't need to answer me anymore :) Thank you for all your help, maybe I should delete this post now?

Comment: No, I don't think you should delete it. You can clarify your question and answer it yourself, or - now it's clear what you're asking - I could write a general answer.

Comment: okay, that will be fine :) If you want to give a general answer I'm happy =) thank you for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the general way this sort of thing proceeds. Let there be some statistic of interest, $T$ (which could for example correspond to a measure of association, or of deviation - lack of fit, such as MSE). You also need to figure out for your $T$ whether very large values, very small values or both large and small values correspond to 'better than chance'. For example, *small* values of MSE are "better", and *large* values of some measure of association are "better". (In the case of C-index, large is better)

The aim is to check whether the particular set of predictions is "better than random" as measured by the statistic - whether the predictions are more associated with the outcomes than you'd expect if it was just due to randomness, for example.

Call the original statistic computed on your data $T^*$.

```
1. Repeat m times:
    shuffle (i.e. permute the labels on) the predictions
    compute T(i) (and save into the i-th position of some m-vector)

2. find out where your original T* is in the distribution - specifically, find the 
   proportion of resampled T statistics at least as extreme in the "better" direction, 
   ... but conventionally you should also count the original sample T* in the proportion 
   of "at least as extreme" as your value (both in the numerator and denominator)
```

That result is an estimated p-value. If $m$ is large, it should be close to the p-value obtained by considering all possible shuffles.

Note that strictly a permutation test is what we call it if we do consider all possible shuffles. If you just sample them with replacement, as here, it's properly called a *randomization test*.