# P-value based on the training error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Assume we have a dataset $Z = \{X_i,y_i\}, i\in [1:n]$. I want to prove that there is a relationship between dependent variables $y$ and independent variables $X$. I do the following:

1. Train a linear model using $Z$, and get the MSE of the training error, let us call it $M$.
2. Shuffle the data, $Z$, 10000 times and get the MSE's of the training error.
3. Define an empirical distribution based on the shuffled-data based model's MSE's, let us call it $D$.
4. Calculate the p-value of $M$ which is defined as $P_D(M)$. If the p-value is less than .05 I reject the null hypothesis that there is a no relationship between $X$ and $y$.

I know a stronger approach is to depend on the testing error not the training error. However, I don't see what is wrong in my approach. If we are afraid of overfitting, then, assume that the null hypothesis is true, similar overfitting values will show up for the shuffled data. Is there something I missed here?

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a very interesting question. Your approach reminded me of the Mantel test, so I did a bit of research. Apparently your procedure and the Mantel test are both examples of permutation tests. Technically, your procedure describes a Monete Carlo test, as a permutation test requires that you evaluate every possible ordering of the data, as opposed to just 10,000 of them. However, the Monte Carlo Test is asymptotically equivalent to a permutation test. The [Wikipedia article on resampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Permutation_tests) provides details. I don't think there is anything wrong with the approach you describe (See [How can permutation test be used for assessing the prediction capability of a model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/137205/240024).) I hope this information will help you to find the answers you need!

Comment: What you're describing is [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)).

Comment: Isn't it distinct? I believe bootstrapping only involves resampling real observations, while this technique involves independently sampling X and y vectors to generate a simulated dataset with combinations of X and y that did not exist in the original data.

Comment: Oh, I meant to reply to the initial post.  Yes, there are differences between bootstrapping and permutation tests.  I'm not taking issue with your discussion, I just wanted to add 'bootstrapping' to the discussion.